# Empty head in custom flatten implementation

Tags: elixir

So basically I tried to implement flatten function myself using some nested recursions. The problem is that I get infinite loop and when checking the actual head it is empty. I just started learning elixir so please don't be too harsh on me.

```elixir
defmodule Test do
  def custom_flatten list do
    custom_flatten list, []
  end
  def custom_flatten [h|t], accumulator do
    custom_flatten [t], [custom_flatten(h) | accumulator]
  end
  def custom_flatten [], accumulator do
    IO.puts "Called empty list match #{accumulator}"
    Enum.reverse accumulator
  end

  def custom_flatten h, accumulator do
    [h|accumulator]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are already doing so, but a good strategy is to look at what the official implementation does. Elixir's implementation just [calls through](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.1/lib/elixir/lib/list.ex#L155) to the [Erlang implementation](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/5c7209c2874849a5a7339e23fdbd9aed1bb935b2/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L627). Here is the Erlang implementation re-written in Elixir:

```elixir
def flatten([], acc), do: acc

def flatten([h | t], acc) when is_list(h) do
  flatten(h, flatten(t, acc))
end

def flatten([h | t], acc) do
  [h | flatten(t, acc)]
end
```

It seems there are a few of problems with your implementation.

1. The terminating condition is when the first argument is an empty list. But as Brett also mentioned, because your recursive call passes `[t]`, which is a single-element list containing the tail list, the terminating condition never happens.
2. You need to use [guards](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/guards.html) to detect if the next element (`h`) is a list or not, to decide whether you need another layer of recursion, or whether the element can be used directly.
3. It looks like your custom behaviour is building up the list in reverse. In that case, you need to use the concatenation (`++`) operator, because when building in reverse, we have to flatten the sub-lists on the fly, then concatenate them to the accumulator (in the Erlang non-reversed implementation, the tail  is always flattened first, so it's not necessary in that case). We also need to make sure we only reverse the final result, otherwise the internal lists will also get reversed during the recursive calls:

```elixir
def flatten(list) do
  list
  |> flatten([])
  |> Enum.reverse()
end

def flatten([], acc), do: acc

def flatten([h | t], acc) when is_list(h) do
  flatten(t, flatten(h, []) ++ acc)
end

def flatten([h | t], acc) do
  flatten(t, [h | acc])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's this line causing you problems:

```
    custom_flatten [t], [custom_flatten(h) | accumulator]
```

If your function had started with `[h | t] = [1, 2, 3]`, `t` would be `[2, 3]`, and you would pass `[[2, 3]]` to the next function. That function would see `[h | t] = [[2, 3]]`, so `h` would be `[2, 3]` and `t` would be `[]`, which would pass `[[]]` to the next function. Then your function would get stuck repeating `[h | t] = [[]]`, where `h` is `[]` and `t` is `[]`.

So really the only problem is you don't want to wrap your `t`. Replacing the line above with something like this should solve the infinite recursion problem.

```
    custom_flatten t, [custom_flatten(h) | accumulator]
```